$3\frac{\zeta'(\sigma)}{\zeta(\sigma)}+4 \Re \frac{\zeta'(\sigma+i t)}{\zeta(\sigma+i t)}+\Re\frac{\zeta'(\sigma+2 i t)}{\zeta(\sigma+2it)}\leq0$
In our script it is used without proof that

For $\sigma>1$ and $t \in \mathbb{R}$
$$
3 \frac{\zeta^{\prime}(\sigma)}{\zeta(\sigma)}+4 \Re \frac{\zeta^{\prime}(\sigma+i t)}{\zeta(\sigma+i t)}+\Re\frac{\zeta^{\prime}(\sigma+2 i t)}{\zeta(\sigma+2 i t)} \leq 0 .
$$
It follows that $\frac{\zeta^{\prime}(s)}{\zeta(s)}$ has no poles $s$ with $\Re(s)=1$ and $s \neq 1$.

I want to prove this statement but require some guidance. It looks similar to this theorem

Theorem A. For $\sigma>1$ and $t \in \mathbb{R}$, we have
$$
\zeta(\sigma)^3|\zeta(\sigma+i t)|^4|\zeta(\sigma+2 i t)| \geq 1.
$$

The claim in question looks like sort of a derivative of this theorem. Any hints or insights on how to proceed?
(Note: For context, $\zeta(s)$ denotes the Riemann zeta function and $\Re(s)$ represents the real part of the complex number $s$).

Hint with $s=\sigma+it$ and $\sigma > 1, t\in\mathbb{R}$: $$\Re\frac{\zeta’(s)}{\zeta(s)}=-\sum_{p\in\mathbb{P}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\log p}{p^{n\sigma}}\cos(nt\log p).$$

Using Euler's product formula
$$\zeta(s)=\prod_{p -\text{prime}}\frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}, \Re(s)>1$$
Then
$$\log(\zeta(s))=-\sum_{p}\log\left(1-p^{-s}\right)$$
And (plus derivation):
$$\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}=
-\sum_{p}\frac{\log(p)\cdot p^{-s}}{1-p^{-s}}=\\
-\sum_{p}\frac{\log(p)}{p^{s}}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{p^s}}\right)=\\
-\sum_{p}\frac{\log(p)}{p^{s}}\cdot\left(\sum\limits_{n=0}\frac{1}{p^{n\cdot s}}\right)=\\
-\sum_{p}\log(p)\cdot\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}\frac{1}{p^{n\cdot s}}\right)$$
Considering $s=\sigma + i t, t\in\mathbb{R}$
$$\frac{\zeta'(\sigma + i t)}{\zeta(\sigma + i t)}=
-\sum_{p}\log(p)\cdot\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}\frac{1}{p^{n\cdot (\sigma + i t)}}\right)=\\
-\sum_{p}\log(p)\cdot\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}\frac{p^{-i\cdot nt}}{p^{n\sigma}}\right)=\\
-\sum_{p}\log(p)\cdot\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}\frac{e^{-i\cdot nt\cdot\log(p)}}{p^{n\sigma}}\right)$$
which is
$$\frac{\zeta'(\sigma + i t)}{\zeta(\sigma + i t)}=
-\sum_{p}\log(p)\cdot\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}\frac{\cos\left(nt\cdot\log(p)\right)-i\sin\left(nt\cdot\log(p)\right)}{p^{n\sigma}}\right)\tag{1}$$
Then
$$\Re\left(\frac{\zeta'(\sigma + i t)}{\zeta(\sigma + i t)}\right)=
-\sum_{p}\log(p)\cdot\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}\frac{\cos(nt\cdot\log(p))}{p^{n\sigma}}\right)\tag{2}$$
Finally
$$3 \frac{\zeta^{\prime}(\sigma)}{\zeta(\sigma)}+4 \Re \left(\frac{\zeta^{\prime}(\sigma+i t)}{\zeta(\sigma+i t)}\right)+\Re\left(\frac{\zeta^{\prime}(\sigma+2 i t)}{\zeta(\sigma+2 i t)}\right)=\\
3 \Re\left(\frac{\zeta^{\prime}(\sigma)}{\zeta(\sigma)}\right)+4 \Re \left(\frac{\zeta^{\prime}(\sigma+i t)}{\zeta(\sigma+i t)}\right)+\Re\left(\frac{\zeta^{\prime}(\sigma+2 i t)}{\zeta(\sigma+2 i t)}\right)=\\
-\sum_{p}\log(p)\cdot\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}\frac{3+4\cos(nt\cdot\log(p))+\cos(2nt\cdot\log(p))}{p^{n\sigma}}\right)\tag{3}$$
The final bit to check is
$$3+4\cos(x)+\cos(2x)=\\
3+4\cos(x)+\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)=\\
2+4\cos(x)+2\cos^2(x)=\\
2\cdot\left(1+\cos(x)\right)^2\geq 0$$
and the result follows from $(3)$.
